# Proving the least common multiple between two elements of a ring exist.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am trying to see if, in the commutative ring $R = \mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-3}\,\,\right],$ the elements $a = 4 = 2\cdot 2 = (1+\sqrt{-3}\,)(1-\sqrt{-3}\,),\quad b = (1+\sqrt{-3}\,)\cdot 2$ have a least common multiple.

What I've done:

$4(2(1+\sqrt{-3}))=8(1+\sqrt{-3})$ is a common multiple of $a$ and $b$. If there exist an $m$ such that $m\mid8(1+\sqrt{-3})$ that could be the least common multiple.

$m\mid8(1+\sqrt{-3})$ implies that $m=8$ (among others) which is a multiple of $4$ ($2\cdot 4$) and $2(1+\sqrt{-3})$, ($2(1+\sqrt{-3})\cdot 2(1-\sqrt{-3})$). Therefore that $m$ exist and it could be the least common multiple of $a$ and $b$.

Comment: What is your definition of lcm here? It looks like you're saying that any divisor of $ab$ has to be the lcm, which is certainly not true.

Comment: Is this an ordered ring? If not, I don't think "least" makes sense

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780358/g-c-d-and-l-c-m-in-mathbbz-sqrt-3).

Comment: @MPW In any ring, lcm is defined using divisibility. In other words, 'least' is meant in the order $x<y$ iff $y$ is a multiple of $x$. The least common multiple of $a,b$ if it exists, is an element $c$ such that $c=am$, $c=bn$ and if $d=am'$ and $d=bn'$, then $d=cK$.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier my definition is the one fishroe just gave. I edited my question. I am not saying $m$ is the lcm, but I know there exists one $m$ that is a divisor of a multiple of $a,b$. Therefore the lcm exists, is that correct?